# Using OR/|| in else if in PHP not working correctly

Tags: php

So, I'm currently using a `elseif()` in PHP but I'm having a problem with the `||`.

My code is as follows:

```
elseif($token_24_check == 0 || $token_48_check == 0)
{
   echo "<script>alert('Please enter a valid token!');</script>";
}
```

The problem is, it does not check either `$token_24_check == 0` or `$token_48_check == 0` but it checks both of them. So if one of them is false it still returns false.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

### UPDATE

Here's the full code from the first line (`if()`) to the last line (`else`)

```
if(empty($token))
{
   echo "<script>alert('Please enter a token!');</script>";
}
elseif($user_check != 0)
{
   echo '<script>alert("You can only redeem 1 token.\nPlease wait until your other token has expired!");</script>';
}
elseif($token_24_check == 0 || $token_48_check == 0)
{
   echo "<script>alert('Please enter a valid token!');</script>";
}
elseif($token_check != 0)
{
   echo "<script>alert('Token already used! Please use a new token');</script>";
}
else
   echo "<script>alert('Token successfully redeemed!');</script>";
}
```

Comment: try `===` in both conditions

Comment: what are you comparing to with the `elseif`? you need an `if(){}` in there to make a comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either @Bsienn

Comment: var_dump(array($token_24_check, $token_48_check)). see the result, post it here. might help

Comment: The `if()` is a couple lines above this one @petebolduc

Comment: Did what you asked @Bsienn. It outputs `array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) }`

Comment: friend, there seems nothing wrong with the code provided. u must be misunderstanding something. ur question is not complete/clear. i cant help more but, post ur code from the first if condition to last else.

Comment: Posted the code from the first `if()` to the last line `else` @Bsienn

Answer (score 0):

As your code is written you are using `else if` which should be `elseif`

## However...

as the code is written you are making a comparison with else in there try:

```
if($token_24_check == 0 || $token_48_check == 0)
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Please enter a valid token!');</script>";
                }
```

## try reversing the if/elseif

`$token_24_check = 0; $token_48_check = 1;` # this 
                                              # or this
`$token_24_check = 1; $token_48_check = 0;` # this fires the ==0

```
if($token_24_check == 0 || $token_48_check == 0)
        {
         echo "<script>alert('== 0');</script>";
        }
    elseif($token_24_check >= 1 || $token_48_check >= 1)
        {
         echo "<script>alert('>= 1');</script>";
        }
```

Comment: I actually have it written as `elseif()`. I suppose I miss typed it here.

Comment: it doesn't matter, `elseif` or `else if`

Comment: Try flipping them where your token check in in the `if(){}` and the alternative is in the `else{}` or elseif(){}` I tested it on my computer and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using a different tag.

Instead of using `||` I used `&&` which I should've using in the first place.

Now it checks if both conditions are 0 and will then `echo` the string.

Thanks everyone for your help and tips. Much appreciated!